# Only use Tor for .onion requests (direct clearnet access)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, clear-net

Is there a way to configure the Tor Browser (or its alternative) to send clearnet requests directly, while retaining the ability to connect to .onion sites? Of course, in this scenario, I couldn't really be concerned about anonymity or privacy.

I just want to access an .onion site that embeds large quantities of content hosted on clearnet without having to route all of that heavy traffic through Tor. Let's say that this website only exists as a Tor Hidden Service. However, for the sake of clarity, all of this content, as well as the hidden service, are completely legal and there's no motivation to keep their use a secret. For example, its author just couldn't be bothered to pay for a static public IP address.

I had no luck trying to find a browser that would allow this kind of dynamic behavior. Frankly, web search results for queries containing "tor" or "onion" are polluted with articles from popular news sources on the various more-or-less illegal darknet content and guides on how to install the Tor Browser, due to their well-crafted SEO.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this with Tor Browser. If you like programming, you could set up Firefox to use a SOCKS proxy, and then write a custom SOCKS proxy that forwards requests to onion addresses to tor's SOCKS proxy, but makes direct requests for non-onion addresses. But hopefully you find an easier way.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I was considering something like that, but I hoped somebody else had already made that effort before me. It seemed like something someone could have already wanted before for a similar purpose.

Comment: Tor2Web allows you to access onion sites without routing your other traffic through tor

Comment: That's a neat trick I didn't consider but I don't really seem to get any of the services of this kind to work. Tor2Web doesn't seem to have been maintained much in more than a year and most of their domains don't work anymore, at least for me. They're either very slow or unstable. I don't think it's caused by my browser. Running my own instance would kind of defeat the purpose, so I'll try looking for one that runs better. The idea is great, but the reality doesn't seem as great as I hoped.